# How to fix F5, F6 keys on Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, backlight, function-keys

On Macbook Pro, <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> seems to be the "keyboard illumination keys".

However, the keyboard's *illumination* doesn't seem to change at all after pressing those keys.

Also, I noticed a small "no entry" sign whenever I hit those keys, how do we fix these problems?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The laptop makes note of ambient lighting and disables keyboard backlight when it's not dark. This is similar to the automatic display brightness system. Both are there to save power.

Your keyboard backlight should work in a dark room or if you cover your iSight camera so the laptop thinks it's dark.

Comment: heys cool, btw where's the sensor?

Comment: @Pacerier: I *think* it's right next to the web camera. (So blocking the webcam makes the computer think it's dark)

Comment: on my 2008 mac book pro 17", the system is quite slow to respond.  After covering up the camera and / or switching off the option in system preferences to automatically dim the backlight, I actually had to wait around a minute (!) before the `f5 and `f6 keys came back to life. I had a lot going on with the computer, but still it was a bit surprising to have to wait so long.